# Combining text file using method

Tags: java, methods, io

Hi everyone I am currently trying to write a program for an assignment that takes 4 separate text files then using a method, combines them into one. I was wondering if someone could help me find out what is wrong with this code. When i try to run it I get a error reading the following:

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: wonder1.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at asig5.combineFile(asig5.java:26)
    at asig5.main(asig5.java:17) "
```

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class asig5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        PrintWriter newtext = new PrintWriter("wonder5.txt");
        File f0 = new File("wonder1.txt");
        File f1 = new File("wonder2.txt");
        File f2 = new File("wonder3.txt");
        File f3 = new File("wonder4.txt");
        combineFile(f0, newtext);
        combineFile(f1, newtext);
        combineFile(f2, newtext);
        combineFile(f3, newtext);

        newtext.close();

    }

    public static void combineFile(File f0, PrintWriter output) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(f0);
        while (input.hasNext()) {

            String part1 = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(part1);
            output.print(part1);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you understand by the log you just posted?

Comment: I dont understand why its not finding the file.

Comment: the files that im trying to combine*

Comment: Are you sure the files are there or you want to create them?

Comment: the files are in my system library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `new File("wonder1.txt")` it means that if your project location is `~/Folder/MyProject`, your file's full path is `~/Folder/MyProject/wonder1.txt`.

You need to provide full path to your file or put your files at the root of your project folder.